# Using v-bottom-navigation in v-window-item will cause falling phenomenon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When using `v-layout` or `v-bottom-navigation` in `v-window-item`, the `v-layout` or `v-bottom-navigation` will fall down when scrolling the page, and how to avoid this phenomenon while keeping the switching animation.

Writing `v-layout` outside of `v-window-item` seems like a solution, but I don't want to write `v-layout` outside.
Because I intend to load different components on each `v-window-item`, each of them has its own separate `v-bottom-navigation`.

```
<template>
  <v-window v-model="onboarding" show-arrows="hover">
    <v-window-item v-for="n in length" :key="`card-${n}`">
      <v-card
        elevation="2"
        height="200"
        class="d-flex align-center justify-center ma-2"
      >
        <h1 class="text-h2">Slide {{ n }}</h1>
      </v-card>

      <v-layout
        style="
          position: fixed;
          justify-content: center;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: cornflowerblue;
        "
      >
        <v-btn class="ma-2">Button</v-btn>
        <v-btn class="ma-2">Button</v-btn>
        <v-btn class="ma-2">Button</v-btn>
      </v-layout>
    </v-window-item>
  </v-window>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      length: 3,
      onboarding: 0,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When you just remove the `position: fixed;` the buttons sit directly below the card. Isn't that what you ask for?

Comment: No, you paste the above code into the App.vue of `https://play.vuetifyjs.com`, and then slide the page, and you will find that in the sliding animation, the button goes up first and then falls down, which is so strange. 
Although disabling animation can avoid this phenomenon, I need this scrolling animation. 
I just hope `v-layout` stays at the bottom and doesn't move casually.

Comment: I want `v-layout` to always be at the bottom of windows. I will actually use `v-bottom-navigation`, but I find that the two phenomena are the same, as long as one can be solved, the other can be solved.